# Using twitter api - what should I do if I don't have a website

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to use Twitter API, and when I logged in at dev.twitter.com a open My Application and started to create new application it ask me about website, but since I don't have a website what should I fill it that field?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I overcame this problem by putting my twitter profile's link instead of other characters as placeholder

You can refer the following link for further information:
http://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/

Answer (score 6):

Just use your personal twitter account.

Website URL: `https://twitter.com/username`

Answer (score 3):

From creation page:

> If you don't have a URL yet, just put a placeholder here but remember to change it later.

Answer (score 1):

The website is required but you can put a placeholder (as suggested also by Twitter). For example your twitter handle, or your github page, will do the job.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It really does not matter if you have website or not. You can generate keys by using any websites like Twitter profile link either.

I used one of the twits link

and got the keys