# Twitter Creating App Failed due to invalid Web URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, twitter, twitter-oauth

I followed this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qL3tZ6yHWMA

And when I reached the step on entering the **Website URL**, I got this error:

[image]

I want to be able to enter localhost only as this is just for school assignment purposes. Any ideas how to enter localhost as the website url?

Comment: Did you try `localhost:56627`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did to solve the issue is just type in
[http://google.com](https://google.com)
, as long as it is a valid domain name, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just using the TwitterAPI for a school assignment and don't have a domain registered for the app to use, you can use pretty much any domain.  I've seen a lot of people just use the URL to their own Twitter timeline. [See this SO post from 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809921/using-twitter-api-what-should-i-do-if-i-dont-have-a-website)

If you were to ever need to use the API in a production environment, you would want to update this URL to the domain that will be using the API.